# Open a picture with Photoshop or Preview based on file location

Tags: finder, graphics

Let's say I want to open pictures from those specific folders with `Photoshop` by default (with double-clicking the file):

```
/Users/bob/Project1/
/Users/bob/Project3/
```

And to open pictures with `Preview` by default in any other location.

I'm not aware of any solution out of the box. Maybe someone has an idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Craig's answer, I found [this very similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169591/dynamically-change-opening-app-according-to-file-folder) that has a great solution using a bash script.

It works surprisingly well, at least for my needs.

The script is wrapped into an application, then the trick is to set up all the `jpg` files (for example) to be open with this application by default.

This setup is easily done with the "Get Info" --> "Open with" --> "Change all" steps.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"
do
  if [ $(dirname "$f") = "/Users/bob/Desktop" ]
  then
    open -a "/Applications/VLC.app" "$f"
  else
    open -a "/Applications/IINA.app" "$f"
  fi
done
```

(As you can notice, this script switch between the two players `VLC` and `INNA`, but you can easily modify it to switch between `Photoshop` and `Preview`. The folders can also can be easily modified to `/Users/bob/Project1/` and `/Users/bob/Project3/` instead of `/Users/bob/Desktop`)

Automator is actually not needed, as it's possible [to turn a bash script into an application from the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269045/306962).

Still, if one prefer using Automator, it looks like this (from there you just run "File --> export" and save your application):

[image: Automator]

Comment: This would definitely do it! Sorry, thought you were looking for an automated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a partial solution with using [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) and Automator.

1st, create an Automator workflow that uses the "Set Application for Files" action on received files to Photoshop.

2nd, create a Hazel rule that runs that Automator script on any images dropped into a specific folder. You could skip Hazel and just create a folder action in Automator but that would fire on any file placed in that folder and that might not be what you want.

Files modified in such a way would still open in Photoshop once removed from that folder, which is why this is only a partial solution.

Comment: Thank you for your great insights. I upvote this. It got me on the right track with a solution using Automator to create a shell script application. I'll add it here for reference.